# Would a person exposed to zero gravity for a long time have trouble riding a bicycle?

Tags: gravity

I just watched this video by Drew Feustel showing him having trouble walking upright after 197 days on ISS:

https://mobile.twitter.com/Astro_Feustel/status/1075889929119547393

They say once you have learned how to ride a bicycle you can never unlearn this skill (crossed hands excused)

It made me wonder: would people returning from space have to learn how to ride a bicycle the same way they have to learn how to walk again? What about hoverboards or Segways?

Comment: AFAIK it's not that they "unlearn" to walk, it's that their sense of balance is messed up once they return from a long space flight and needs some time getting used to gravity again.

Comment: @darkdust: this is interesting! But how exactly is it different from "unlearn"?

Comment: @DarkDust I've just asked [What exactly makes it difficult for astronauts to walk immediately after landing after extended stays in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33072/12102)

Answer (score 4):

The overwhelming majority of physical issues stemming from prolonged spaceflight are due to loss of muscle and bone mass. Astronauts typically make a full recovery shortly (few months) after their return to Earth's gravity well. Provided they have the physical strength to push the pedals and keep the bike upright, a returning astronaut shouldn't have any trouble riding a bike.

Comment: But not immediately after landing.